# Github copy file from on branch to another (Browser GUI)

Tags: github

new to GitHub i have done a file in a branch.
now it would like to copy this file from a branch to another branch, but can't find out how to do it in a Web GUI i use.
thanks to Point to a Information site or the answer
have a nice day
vinc

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if git hub provides an actual feature for copying files from one branch to another, but this should do what you want

- open two browser tabs with your github repo

  - 1. with the "source" branch you want to copy from
  - 2. with the github destination branch you want to copy to
- select the "destination" branch where you want to create the new file
- click the `+` to create a new file - give it the name you want
- Go back to the "source" branch and copy the code, then paste it into the new file in the "destination branch"

Comment: LOL, Thanks a lot, i was hoping there is a better solutien - then this. I have done something similar

Comment: Cool, If it helped solved your problem, you can select the answer by clicking the big tick

Comment: i hope there is a more profesional solution then this ;-)

Comment: I know what you mean, You could ask github directly, but I suspect they would say they only provide the web gui as a "basic" interface. If you look at the way most people use github, you would clone the repo you want to work on, make your changes then push back to the git hub repo.

Comment: i have done so, but when you make a change, Test it, change again, it show a lots of file and not only the last final file

Comment: are you clicking on the button that looks like this `<>` ?, that will show all files in the repo at that commit. if you click the link that looks like `f3g44g` (first few letters of hash) it will show only the changes in the commit - but how to view files after commits/changes is another separate question

Comment: Upvoted because this is also the only way that I'm aware of to do it via the web interface, , and I just had to do this. But, this is a really lousy solution. Hopefully GitHub adds a "copy" button.